# How to strip all anchor tags and href attribute only?

Tags: php, html, regex, anchor

I have a scenario in which I need to strip all the anchors from the HTML content, but when doing so I don't want to strip the `href` part of anchor tags.

Currently I am using this regexp to strip anchors using `preg_replace()`.

```
<a [^>]*> strips all the anchor tag
<a.+href\=[\"|\'](.+)[\"|\'].*\>.*\<\/a\> - matches href
```

example string:
    "anchor href="mailto:xyz@gmail.com">namemail anchor"

and after doing preg_replace() I should get "mailto:xyz@gmail.com" string as the text rest all should be stripped.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/499581) might be helpful.

Comment: You cannot successfully/reliably achieve this with a regular expression.

Comment: @Jon  [Oh yes you can](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
~<a.+?href=(["'])(.+?)\1.*?>.*?</a>~is
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Detailed description

```
~<a.+?href=(["'])(.+?)\1.*?>.*?</a>~is

<a    # matches the characters <a literally (case sensitive)
.+?   # matches any character, the least possible
href= # matches the characters href= literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing group (["'])
    ["'] # matches a single character. Either " or '
2nd Capturing group (.+?)
    .+?  # matches any character, the least possible
\1    # matches a single character corresponding the character found in first capturing group.
.*?   # matches zero or more characters, the least possible
>     # matches the character > literally
.*?   # matches zero or more characters, the least possible
</a>  # matches the characters </a> literally (case sensitive)
i modifier: ignore case
s modifier: single line. Dot matches newline characters

NOTA: The ~ between the regex delimit it and allow us to don't escape /.
```

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/fX1fP1

#### Some notes

- `[\"|\']`

  Don't over excape your escape. Only escape metacharacters when you want to match them explicitly. Use `["|']` instead.
- `["|']`

  Don't use `|` inside a character class unless you want to match it. The characters inside a character class are already `OR`ed. Check the descriptions below:

  When you type `["|']`, the regex flavor sees:
  [image: Regular expression visualization]

  When you type `["']`, the regex flavor sees:
  [image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I am using this in php
$strText = '<b>Name&lt;<a href="mailto:xyz@gmail.com">Nameemail</a>&gt;</b>';

    $strText = 
preg_replace( '#<a.+?href=[\"\']([^"\']+)["\'].*?\>.*?\    <\/a>#is', '', $strText );

But it is not preserving the href part, stripping the whole anchor tag.

Comment: @user2173474 You don't need to escape the first double quotes, the > and the /.

Comment: While this is a good regular expression and a good explanation, it will not successfully match/replace all valid URLs. Specifically those URLs which contain either the `'` or the `"` character. To achieve what the OP wants, you CANNOT use a regex. You MUST parse the HTML.

Comment: This breaks for the anchor `<a href='http://google.com/search?q="cheese"'>search for cheese</a>` and there is no PCRE modifier `g` in PHP, you need to use `preg_replace_all()` instead.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for your comments. I have improved the regex regarding this issue.

Comment: @Alex `<a href='http://google.com/search?q=\'cheese\''>search for cheese</a>` breaks the new regex

Comment: Apologies for poking holes in your answer, it's just the wrong solution to the problem and the OP needs to learn that regex can't usually be used to process HTML.

Comment: @Jon Did OP precise if that the last "hole" is present within his/her context ?

Comment: @Alex no, sorry, I got a bit over-zealous there with my anti-regex opinion!

Answer (score 1):

```
$html = '<a href="http://www..." x=asdasda?></a>';
$html = preg_replace("|<a[^>]*href\s*=\s*([\"'])([^\"']*)\\1[^>]*>[^<]*</a>|si", "$2", $html);
```

Output:

```
http://www...
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `$html = "<a href='http://google.com/search?q=\"cheese\"'>search for cheese</a>";`

Comment: its worked for me I got naked link from html formated link like this `<a href="http://exmple.com/author/vistor/" title="some" relation="author" >profile</a>` The result is `http://exmple.com/author/vistor/`

Answer (score 1):

You'll be much more successful by parsing the HTML using DOMDocument, instead of trying to use a regular expression:

Here's a proof-of-concept of what you <strike>could</strike> should do instead:

```
function replaceAnchorTags($html) {
    //Intialise document using provided HTML
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);         //suppress invalid HTML warnings
    $doc_elem = $doc->documentElement;

    traverse($doc, $doc_elem);
    return $doc->saveHTML();
}

function traverse(&$doc, $elem) {
    if ($elem->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE and $elem->tagName == "a") {
        $href = $elem->getAttribute("href");
        // Obviously here you might want to keep the anchor's inner HTML as
        // well as the URL...
        $text_replacement = $doc->createTextNode($href);
        $elem->parentNode->replaceChild($text_replacement, $elem);
    }

    if ($elem->hasChildNodes()) {
        $children = $elem->childNodes;
        for ($i=0, $max=$children->length; $i<$max; $i++) {
            traverse($doc, $children->item($i));
        }
    }
}

$html = "<p>Hello <a href='http://twitter.com'>Brave New</a> World</p>";

echo replaceAnchorTags($html);
```